# Abpersonviewcontroller showing no details

Tags: ios

i want to show the user the contact page of a person but its showing null . my code is below i am only getting a black contact page with an empty imagebox

```
    ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

NSDictionary *dic = [arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

ABRecordRef ref = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[dic objectForKey:@"ABRecordRef"];

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

NSLog(@"%@",ref);

ABRecordID recId = ABRecordGetRecordID(ref);

personController.displayedPerson = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, recId);

personController.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: kABPersonNicknameProperty],
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel],
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonAddressProperty],
                                        nil];


personController.allowsEditing = YES;
personController.personViewDelegate = self;     
personController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Return" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(wapis)];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:personController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Are you sure `ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID` returns a valid person? Does this contact have nickname, phone or address?

Comment: what's the problem you're facing? maybe you should start a new question..